# how to use openfiledialog properly?

Tags: c#

I'm learning how to use `OpenFileDialog`; here is the code I am using:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;

namespace my_album
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            MyForm album = new MyForm();
            Application.Run(album);
        }
    }

    public class MyForm : Form
    {
        private Button btnLoad;
        private PictureBox pboxPhoto;
        public MyForm()
        {
            Size = new Size(400, 400);
            Text = "Hello Form";
            Button btnLoad = new Button();
            btnLoad.Text = "&Load";
            //btnLoad.Location = new Point(20, 20);
            //b.Size = new Size(20, 30);
            btnLoad.Left = 10;
            btnLoad.Top = 10;
            btnLoad.Click += ButtonClickHandler;

            pboxPhoto = new PictureBox();
            pboxPhoto.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
            pboxPhoto.Width = Width / 2;
            pboxPhoto.Height = Height / 2;
            pboxPhoto.Left = (Width - pboxPhoto.Width) / 2;
            pboxPhoto.Top = (Height - pboxPhoto.Height) / 2;
            pboxPhoto.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
            Controls.Add(pboxPhoto);
            Controls.Add(btnLoad);
        }


        private void ButtonClickHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("kkk");
            OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
            dlg.InitialDirectory = @"c:\";
            dlg.Filter = "All files (*.*)|*.*|All files (*.*)|*.*";
            if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("open ok");
            }

            dlg.Dispose();
        }

        public override sealed string Text
        {
            get { return base.Text; }
            set { base.Text = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever I press the load button, the program is down. Why is that?

If I comment the line with `dlg.ShowDialog()` it will work so that must be the error, but I don't know how to fix it.

I am using c# and Visual Studio 2012

Comment: Get rid of the ` dlg.Dispose();` line. You shouldn't need to explicitly dispose a managed object like a UI control.

Answer (score 0):

The `dlg.Dispose();` is redundant to the control since it is handled internally to the control. When you select a file, the program can try and lock it, which if you are using the selected file somewhere else in the program could cause problems. if for some reason, you really needed check to see if the resource is closed then you could change it to

```
if (dlg != null)
   {
       dlg.Dispose();
   }
```

If some other unexpected error occurs, then putting a try catch around the code would trap it and give you more info.

```
    private void ButtonClickHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("kkk");
        try
        {
            OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
            dlg.InitialDirectory = @"c:\";
            dlg.Filter = "All files (*.*)|*.*|All files (*.*)|*.*";
            if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("open ok");
            }
        } catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Dialog open error occurred: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your help. finally i find that i don't have [STAThread] before Main() function :(